# How to create and save a 1x1 pixel transparent png using R?

Tags: r, png, transparency

I would like to create a 1x1 pixel transparent png file in R. 
Is there any way to do so or do i have to "copy" a premade 1x1 pixel png?

I've tryed

```
empty_frame = imfill(x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, val = "transparent", dim = NULL)
```

but this does not create a transparent pixel but a 1x1 white pixel.

I need the 1x1 pixel .png file as a placeholder in case there are no data to be plotted.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do, and we can't see what you've tried. Why do you want a single pixel?

Comment: @camille i need it as kind of a "placeholder" in case there is no data to be plotted. I've tried `imager::imfill(1,1,val=1)` which gives me a 1x1 pixel, but i am not fully sure if it is truely transparent (as a placeholder a 1x1 white pixel would be just as good, but right now im curious about how to create it transparent, if possible)

Comment: This seems.. simple. Although i am no genious for images, wouldnt setting the `alpha` value to 0 make it transparent. `val = rgb( 1, 1, 1,  0)`. The first 3 values should not matter, as `alpha = 0` makes the colour fill be null. Works for anything like `plot(y = 1:5, x = 1:5 + 3, col = rgb(1, 1, 1, 0))`, so i cant see why it wouldn't work, across all 3 layers of a RGB image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be using `png::writePNG`:

```
png::writePNG(array(0, dim = c(1,1,4)), "pixel.png")
```

This creates a transparent 1x1 pixel (with 4 channels set at zero, for each of RGB and alpha), which I confirmed by opening it up in GIMP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm going to try it out and will accept your answer afterwars. Edit: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!